# What's wrong with my front face only option?

Tags: sculpting, artifacts, brushes

I'm new to Blender, and I'm following a tutorial.
But when I'm sculpting, I have a problem with the rendering compared to the video.
In the tutorial, we use the "Clay strips" brush with an alpha texture to create rocks.
When I don't activate the "Front faces only" option, everything behaves correctly (except of course that the rear faces are affected, which I don't want).
And when I activate the option, I get a completely different rendering (see image).
For the record, I'm using blender version 4.0.2.0.
And it doesn't seem to come from the alpha texture. I've tested with different alphas and always get the same result.

[image: Visual with and without "Front faces only" option]

Comment: Yeah I know it's a bit difficult to understand.
Maybe I can send you my scene so you'll be able to check if I use a parameter incorrectly, or maybe my blender configuration is wrong.
I tried to flip normals, but I have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

It's a shot in the dark but have you checked if your face orientation is correct? You can flip them by selecting your geometry, going into *Edit Mode* under the Top Bar Menu *Mesh  > Normals > Flip*. Maybe you are painting on the backside of your model which would explain why nothing happens when checking front face only

Answer (score 0):

According to this link https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/116758

1. Turn off Font Face only
2. Turn on [View Normal] in the brush tab under the auto mask section
3. Lower the falloff to 0 since the Front Face only is turned off

I hope that helps